# How to handle query string in PHP?

Tags: php

How to handle query string? I have search, sort, show per rows and pagination function for my project? what is the best way to handle this things? i stucked up in this part of my project. Please help me.

The url is something like this :

http://www.example.com/content.php?sort=title&ord=asc&page=2&perrows=250

Comment: Please give me any way on how to maninupate this problem is there any suggestion?

Comment: You need to describe your goal. what do you mean by "handle the query string"?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is unclear what your problem is. What are you trying to achieve? Where are you stuck? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Comment: Don't you think you are asking something like 'what is the best way to build a house?'

Comment: something like that. Is there any way on how to maintain the query string even if the user click the pagination it maintains the sort,show per rows order

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the contents of the query string through the `$_GET` array. In your case for example `$_GET['sort']` will be set to `'title'`.

You can put then these variables within a MySQL query.

Make sure you are aware of [Sql Injection](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php) though!

Answer (score 0):

You would retrieve them from the query string thus:

```
$sort = $_GET['sort'];
$order = $_GET['ord'];
$page = intval($_GET['page']);
$rows = intval($_GET['perrows']);
```

You can also use $_REQUEST['sort'] if the values may be returned by get, post or cookies, request is a bag off all of these properties.